# Verificar se a entrada é um número inteiro

Tags: c, funções, lógica

Preciso de uma função que leia uma entrada do teclado e valide se ela é um número inteiro (negativo ou positivo). Se for, ela deve retornar o valor. Senão, ela deve relatar que a entrada é inválida para o usuário e pedir novamente.

A função que escrevi valida isso, porém, ela falha se o usuário informar caracteres misturados com números. Fora que também há um problema na impressão. O printf é executado a quantidade de vezes que o usuario digitou um caracter inválido. Desde já, agradeço paciência.

Exemplos de Entrada e Saída:

> Entrada 15 Saída Return 15;
>
> Entrada -5 Saida Return -5;
>
> Entrada 0 Saida Return 0;
>
> Entrada asefga*/+. Saída Printf("Numero Inválido") scanf Novamente;
>
> Entrada sdasddddas55546 Saída Printf("Numero Inválido") scanf
>   Novamente;

Basicamente, o scanf deve retornar qualquer `int`, e continuar o do while enquanto alguma `char` for digitado;

```
int InserirValido(){

    int valor;
    int x=1;

    do
    {
        x =scanf("%d", &valor);
        getchar();

        if(x==0)
            printf("Numero Inválido");

    }while(x==0);

    return valor;
}
```

Comment: já tentou criar um bloco try/catch?

Comment: Perdão, mas ainda não cheguei nisso. Iniciei ADS a pouco tempo, estou em ponteiros.

Comment: @WalterFelipe em c?

Comment: Roberto, poderia por exemplo de como devem ser as entradas e saídas?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Ex: Entrada 15
Saída Return 15;
//Entrada -5
Saida Return -5;
//Entrada 0
Saida Return 0;
//Entrada asefga*/+.
Saída Printf("Numero Inválido")
scanf Novamente;

//Entrada sdasddddas55546
Saída Printf("Numero Inválido")
scanf Novamente;
// Deu pra entender?

Comment: @RobertoKennedy bote no texto da questão

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Ah, ok

Comment: Você está querendo uma função que determina se a entrada possui apenas números, é isso?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Quase isso, a função deve retornar apenas numeros, sim. Enquanto o usuário digitar qualquer tipo de char, o do while deve se repetir. Minha função atual, está aceitando quando o usuário digita letra e numero junto, cancelando todos os chars e colocando na variavel os numeros; Preciso que essa função Informe "numero inválido" enquanto estiver sendo digitado caracteres;

Comment: E se o número tiver dois dígitos?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida, pode aceitar também, qualquer int, com um ou dez digitos, seja ele positivo ou negativo;

Comment: Entendi. Vou escrever a resposta aqui.

Comment: Obrigado! Aguardo

Comment: Nenhuma tentativa com expressões regulares ainda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema aqui é que você está usando `scanf`, que está interpretando a entrada como número indepentende do que realmente tem lá. O que você pode fazer é ler sua entrada como texto e depois usar a função `strtol` na sua entrada. Essa função já faz as duas coisas: converte para número e relata erros. Um código que faz isso ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long ler_apenas_se_for_inteiro();

int main() {
    printf("%ld", ler_apenas_se_for_inteiro());
    return 0;
}

long ler_apenas_se_for_inteiro(){
    char buffer_de_entrada[64];
    char* onde_a_funcao_de_conversao_parou;

    while (1) {
        fgets(buffer_de_entrada, 64, stdin);
        long numero_lido = strtol(buffer_de_entrada, &onde_a_funcao_de_conversao_parou, 0);

        /* Se o número resultante é zero e o ponteiro que aponta para o caractere da string
         * no final da conversão não andou é porque não ocorreu conversão, ou seja, falhou. Além disso, o caractere onde a conversão parou
         * tem que ser uma quebra de linha, caso contrário há caracteres não numéricos
         * que foram ignorados pelo strtol, o que significa que a entrada 
         * não possui somente números.
         */
        if ((numero_lido == 0 && onde_a_funcao_de_conversao_parou == buffer_de_entrada)
            || *onde_a_funcao_de_conversao_parou != '\n') {
            printf("Número inválido. Digite novamente.\n");
            continue;
        } else {
            return numero_lido;
        }
    }

}
```

A função está retornando `long`. Você pode adaptar converter para `int` se for preciso. Você também pode querer colocar mais validações caso a pessoa digite um número maior do que o tamanho do `long`. Veja [A documentação da função](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) para maiores detalhes.

Comment: Elegante. Só o último ponto-e-vírgula no final do bloco da função `lerApenasSeForInteiro` que é desnecessário

Comment: Nem sei como ele foi parar aí. Já vou tirar. :)

Comment: @PabloAlmeida, antes de tudo obrigado pela atenção, porém o teste ainda contem algumas falhas. A mais critica é quando o usuario digita numero e letras. Seu programa funciona bem, caso a letra seja digitado primeiro, porém, ao digitar Ex:"123abc", ela faz a mesma que a minha, ignora o char e pega o numero. Abraços

Comment: Tem razão, @RobertoKennedy. Eu tinha testado apenas com letras seguidas de números. Agora está resolvido para "123abc" também. Veja a mudança no if e a explicação no comentário.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida, Genial! Muito obrigado mesmo!